# Place files on a Bluemix container volume

Tags: upload, containers, ibm-cloud, volume

I have a docker image that requires post-build configuration files to work. These are normally placed on a host directory that is mounted in the container, i.e., `docker run -v /src/config:/usr/local/config ...`

Can this be done on Bluemix as well? i.e., create a volume, upload files and then start the container?

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix does have [recommended approaches for adding files to a volume.](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_volumes_mount)

To summarize, two methods are suggested:

(1) Use `wget` inside the container (`cf ic exec`) once the container is started to download data onto the volume mount folder.

(2) Add the files as part of the image build, and create a container startup script that copies files from a folder in the container to the volume mount folder.

Regardless of the approach, a volume needs to be mounted to a container, and the container needs to be started to add files to the volume through the container.

Comment: The link above (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_volumes_mount) brings to a 404 page. Where would be a current version of this page?

Comment: Try this: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_volumes_ov.html#container_volumes_mount

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a volume to be used by an IBM container.

Here is the command to create a new volume:

```
$ cf ic volume create vol_name
```

After volume is created you can start your container like this:

```
$ cf ic run -v vol_name:/usr/local/config --name my_container my_image
```

You can read complete documentation on volumes in the link below:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_volumes_ov

Comment: The core of the issue is being able to upload files to a volume, not volume creation or mapping.

Comment: It occurred to me that one can create a volume the usual way (`cf ic volume create ...`), start an 'auxiliary' container with that volume mapped, and then run a 'server' of some sort in that container (i.e., ssh/http/ftp server), thus allowing one to upload files onto that volume. Once files are uploaded, the aux container can be stopped as the files stay on the volume (it's persistent) and the primary container can go about its business and complete the post-build configuration.